# Oracle - Need Help w/finding Specific City in Tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm new to Oracle and having trouble finding how to search the tables by specific city. I've looked around and a few examples come up but I don't know if I'm on the right track or not. See my examples below.

Can someone please help?

```
SELECT company, city
FROM customer
WHERE city = 'Sunnyvale', 'Redwood City';
```

Comment: Fine, also do you mind the case match too?

Comment: Hi Maheswaran, I'm not familiar with your lingo. Can you please explain?

Comment: Also, I'm having trouble with the apostrophe in Oracle. Is there a reason why it only hooks to the right when I'm in sqlplus?

Comment: The issue you're having is that you never explain how you connect to the database instance. Which client are you using? Is it SQL Developer or the SQLPlus CLI or the Oracle Enterprise manager. It's like the single quote is not escaped properly.

Comment: It should be called a Single quote than a apostrophe. and previously I was meaning like, you want to look for the city name case sensitive or not. Example, search for Redwood and not REDWOOD!

Comment: I'm using SQLPLUS and ORACLE SQL Developer.

Comment: how do i make single quotes in sqlplus?

Comment: @goodgirlatx347 - what you've used in the question is fine; if you have your SQL*Plus session using a font that displays a single quote (`'`) as if it's a 'smart' quote (’) it will look odd but doesn't matter. Most people use a monospace font for coding to make things neater - Consolas, for example, which is the default font used for code here - including making columns line up, making quotes straight, and being able to distinguish a capital `O` from `0`.

Comment: You don't have "*trouble with the apostrophe **in Oracle***" - if at all you have trouble with apostrophe  in whatever SQL (GUI) client you are using. "Oracle" (the database) is not the thing where you type in your queries.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT company, city 
FROM customer 
WHERE city in ( 'Sunnyvale', 'Redwood City');
```

Comment: this is probably a weird question. but when i go and use the '' in Oracle, it only curves to the left, so I'm unable to close the city name...

Comment: Weird indeed. What kind of client are you using?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT Distinct company, city 
FROM customer 
WHERE city = 'Sunnyvale' or  city ='Redwood City';
```

if this is not  working, you need to use this statement to show your table structure, if you are sure of creating the table structure

```
DESCRIBE customer;
```

it suppose to bring the table info